# Creating large metadata table to map out storage

Tags: disk-usage, storage

I would like to figure out how to manage my storage, which has been quite large. The idea would be to see unnecessary files, and archive/delete.

At the moment, I am simply doing `du -h max-depth 1 and piping the outputs into text files.

However, I would like more information in order to figure out how to archive/delete my current storage.

---What is the best way I could get the file type and size for all files, recursively? This would be a quick way to check for intermediate files which are useless

---I was thinking about outputting all file metadata (i.e. data user, file type, file size, timestamp) into one large tsv file, so I could subset this in Python/R based on size and file type. Is this possible? How would we go about getting this information?

---Are there methods to look at storage versus time?

---Are there any other diagnostics/fancy visualizations which could help me figure out how to organize/archive/delete the data currently stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but not good enough for an answer.  Sorry about that.

> ---What is the best way I could get the file type and size for all files, recursively? This would be a quick way to check for intermediate files which are useless

Not sure about the "best" part, but first hit on Google searching for "advanced disk usage linux" leads to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98382/advanced-disk-usage-analyzing-software).

> ---I was thinking about outputting all file metadata (i.e. data user, file type, file size, timestamp) into one large tsv file, so I could subset this in Python/R based on size and file type. Is this possible? How would we go about getting this information?

With Python, sure: just use `os.walk()` to recurse the directory and print out all relevant information about each file.  I'd probably use SQLite as an output format instead of TSV though.

> ---Are there methods to look at storage versus time?

You can run `du -s` periodically and feed the results to a RRD database.  Then you can make nice graphs out of it.

> ---Are there any other diagnostics/fancy visualizations which could help me figure out how to organize/archive/delete the data currently stored?

There should be, but I'm skeptical about how useful they are for your particular situation.